# Laravel 8: how to translate two factor authentication default message

Tags: laravel-8, fortify

I'm usign Laravel Fortify and i want translate this default message how do it?

> The provided two factor authentication code was invalid.

I found this message in this address but this is source and i can't change it

> src/Http/Responses/FailedTwoFactorLoginResponse.php

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    $message = __('The provided two factor authentication code was invalid.');

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'code' => [$message],
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['email' => $message]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and develop Localization? Seems that message only need the locale. for apply the languages things